# How to check if a python string is a valid Bengali word using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I am trying to test if a word is a valid Bengali word which may contain Bengali letters, vowel markers, 'Hasanta' ("্"), Bengali digits, all punctuation symbols including Bengali "।". We can test this easily for English using regex patter `"\w+"`, but I cannot find any way to do this in Bengali.

For example, these strings: `"আমি"`, `"ভাত"`, `"খাই।"`, `"১২৩"` should be detected as valid Bengali words, but `"I"`, `"eat"`, `"rice"`, `"123"` should be detected as invalid words.

Comment: Any data sample?

Comment: You can use this library : https://github.com/sagorbrur/bnlp

Comment: @DevangSanghani why do not write it as an answer?)

Comment: Interesting, `\p{Bengali}` [does not fully](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqs8vyilWMFWIVrpwbK2B8vWPVi2X0lHAchZ@2DZvgfLlkA408Cc9gdLIfzlyx8sX/Fg@UoQxxNEpCaWgKiizORUEG1oZKwUy5WWX6QAMl4hMw9MF1txKQBBQVFmXokGWERHQd3WTl1HISk/P0cD7B69tNKcnNzEkuQMjSL1mIJqp9S89MSczFptoCqQDk1NBc3//wE) match `খাই।`, it looks like the `‎0964 DEVANAGARI DANDA` at the end prevents it from matching.

Comment: `।` is the period of bengali, so it needed to be identified correctly.

Comment: So what are the rules? What is a valid string? Bengai + Devanagari chars? Or Bengali letters (one or more) any non-letters anywhere? [Does this work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqs8vyilWMFWIVrpwbK2B8vWPVi2X0lHAchZ@2DZvgfLlkA408Cc9gdLIfzlyx8sX/Fg@UoQxxNEpCaWgKiizORUEG1oZKwUy5WWX6QAMl4hMw9MF1txKQBBQVFmXokGWERHQd3WTl1HISk/P0cD7B69tNKcnNzEkuQMjSL1mIBqn1qtmIJqp9S89MSczFptDXsrsKA2sqCmFkQh0CCQoZqaCpr//wMA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `pip install regex` and use

```py
bool(regex.fullmatch(r'\P{L}*\p{Bengali}+(?:\P{L}+\p{Bengali}+)*\P{L}*', word)
```

Note that `regex.fullmatch` will require a full string to match the following pattern:

- `\P{L}*` - zero or more non-letter chars
- `\p{Bengali}+` - one or more Bengali chars
- `(?:\P{L}+\p{Bengali}+)*` - zero or more sequences of one or more non-letter chars and then one or more Bengali chars
- `\P{L}*` - zero or more non-letter chars.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqs8vyilWMFWIVrpwbK2B8vWPVi2X0lHAchZ@2DZvgfLlkA408Cc9gdLIfzlyx8sX/Fg@UoQxxNEpCaWgKiizORUEG1oZKwUy5WWX6QAMl4hMw9MF1txKQBBQVFmXokGWERHQd3WTl1HISk/P0cD7B69tNKcnNzEkuQMjSL1mIBqn1qtmIJqp9S89MSczFptDXsrsKA2sqCmFkQh0CCQoZqaCpr//wMA):

```py
import regex
words = ["আমি", "ভাত", "খাই।", "১২৩", "I", "eat", "rice", "123"]
for word in words:
    print( word, '=>', bool(regex.fullmatch(r'\P{L}*\p{Bengali}+(?:\P{L}+\p{Bengali}+)*\P{L}*', word)) )
```

Output:

```
আমি => True
ভাত => True
খাই। => True
১২৩ => True
I => False
eat => False
rice => False
123 => False
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import regex

bengali_regex = r"\P{L}*\p{Bengali}+(?:\P{L}+\p{Bengali}+)*\P{L}*"
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "আমি")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "ভাত")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "খাই।")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "১২৩")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "I")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "eat")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "rice")))
print(bool(regex.fullmatch(bengali_regex, "123")))
```